# Unable to make the HTTP POST request with the AWS signature in drupal 8 / PHP

Tags: php, aws-sdk, drupal-8, guzzle

We are unable to make the HTTP POST request call to fetch the results and note that autherization type is AWS signature authorization.

In Drupal -8, we have tried with 'AWS connector' module but can not find the exact service for the HTTP POST request with the AWS signature authorization.

Notes:
I got some info on this at drupalize.me site.

```
<code>
$client = \Drupal::httpClient();
  $request = $client->get('https://api.github.com/user', [
    'auth' => ['username','password']
  ]);
  $response = $request->getBody();
(Ref: https://drupalize.me/blog/201512/speak-http-drupal-httpclient)

</code>
```

The auth is for above is basic authentication. But I need for “AWS Signature”

We have tried the below curl code and not able to get the any result. Its showing the white blank screen without any errors.

```
<code>
 $startTimestamp = time(); 
    $amz = gmdate('Ymd\THis\Z', $startTimestamp);
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "https://api-runtime.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/endpoint",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\n\t\"campaignArn\":\"arn:aws:test:us-east-1:12456:campaign/test\",\n\t\"numResults\":2,\n\t\"userId\":\"400\"\n}",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        '"authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=**********/20191205/us-east-1/Test/aws4_request, 
      SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, 
      Signature=' . $signature . '"',
        '"cache-control: no-cache"',
        '"content-type: application/json"',
        '"host: test-runtime.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"',
        '"x-amz-date:' . $amz . '"',
        '"x-amz-target: getrecommendations"'
      ),
    )); 
$result = curl_exec($curl);
if($result === false) {
    echo "Error in cURL : " . curl_error($curl);
}
else {
  echo 'no error'.$result;
}
```

Please check and share the valuable inputs / reference.

Comment: why don't you use [AWS PHP SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php)

Comment: We can use the https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php, but am not able to get the exact example for the “AWS Signature” authentication.

Comment: You will not need to worry about generating signature. All handled by the sdk